# Ip Conflict Event 4199

Tags: networking, dell, dell-poweredge

I have a Dell server, which after a reboot is unable to use the IP address it had prior to the reboot. and I see an error message like the one below:

> Error: The system detected an address conflict for IP address 10.x.x.x with the system having network hardware address 02-24-24-24-24-24. Network operations on this system may be disrupted as a result.

Comment: log into your switches and find out where the MAC is on your network. Failing that, try connecting to the original IP to try and determine which device is causing the conflict

Comment: Is that the real MAC from the error message?

Answer (score 2):

You have an IP address conflict.  That means something else on your network is already using the IP address you assigned to the server.

Pick a new, **unused** IP address for either the server or the something else to resolve this.

Comment: No other device has this IP. But connecting to the switch we discovered that a proxy-arp rules was applyed today by network team. Deliting it everhithing go fine. Thanks to all